# Confused about live method

Tags: jquery

I am fallowing jquery tutorials on the internet and I have found a simple code about how to use live method.I think live method is deprecated so changed the code like this below But ıt doesnt work What am i doing wrong.Thank in advance

```
$(function () {
     $("p").on("click", function () {
          click: function () {
             $(this).after("<p>click</p>");
          },
          mouseover: function () {
             $(this).addClass("deneme");
          },
          mouseout: function () {
             $(this).removeClass("deneme");
          }
     });
});
```

Comment: normally you won't assign click function to all `<p>` ...

Comment: You aren't delegating events here. If you want to delegate it, you need to bind events to any statice container and pass string selector, e.g: `$(document).on({*/events*/}, 'p');`

Comment: Could you tell us what you're trying to do? The code you've shown is a mish-mash of delegated and static event handlers, which is syntactically incorrect

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is totally a Syntax Error, don't you see?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Well, i didn't caught it. You are correct, it doesn't make sense

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ey fraudu.. You edited your comment! :P

Comment: @PraveenKumar :P still, it's not clear what the OP is trying to do. His code is a mix of providing an object to `on()` and a delegated event handler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan True that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You must bind `.on` to static elements, not dynamic.
2. Use call as object *OR* as normal (separate for every event).

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on({
    click: function() {
      $(this).after("<p>click</p>");

    },
    mouseover: function() {
      $(this).addClass("deneme");

    },
    mouseout: function() {
      $(this).removeClass("deneme");
    }

  }, 'p');
});
```

```css
.deneme {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>ACTION!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using trying to use `on` with multiple events on same element then remove `"click", function ()` and try it like,

```
$(function () {
     $("p").on({
          click: function () {
             $(this).after("<p>click</p>");
          },
          mouseover: function () {
             $(this).addClass("deneme");
          },
          mouseout: function () {
             $(this).removeClass("deneme");
          }
     });
});
```